# targeting and centering twitter bootstrap fields in form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that I want the fields to be centered in the middle of the page. Currently the form is almost centered, but the fields are not.

Here is a pic of the view. You can see the word "Start" is centered, but the form is not.
[image: http://postimg.org/image/hep95pl8h/]

The form fields need to be centered. Like the tumblr layout.

Here is my markup in my view.

```
<h1 class="center">Start</h1>
        <form class="create_account"  id="login" action="{{ URL::route('account-create-post') }}" method="post">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <div class="form-group">


                <br>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type='text' name='first_name' required placeholder="First Name"{{ (Input::old('first_name')) ? ' value"' . e(Input::old('first_name')) . '"' : '' }}>
                       <div class="errors">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <br>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type='text' name='last_name' required placeholder="Last Name" {{ (Input::old('last_name')) ? ' value"' . e(Input::old('last_name')) . '"' : '' }}>
                       <div class="errors">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <br>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type='email' name='email' required placeholder="Email" {{ (Input::old('email')) ? ' value"' . e(Input::old('email')) . '"' : '' }}>
                       <div class="errors">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <br>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type='text' name='username' required placeholder="Username" {{ (Input::old('username')) ? ' value"' . e(Input::old('username')) . '"' : '' }}>
                       <div class="errors">


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <br>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type='password' name='password' required placeholder="Password" />
                <div class="errors">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <br>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" type='password' name='password_again' required placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                <div class="errors">

                </div>
            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Start Apologizing">
            <!-- pass token related to session-protects against csrf -->
            {{ Form::token() }}
        </form>
```

Here is my css

```
.create_account {
width: 400px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.create_account input {
width: 80%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.input-group {width:80%; margin:0 auto;}
.create_account input {width:100%}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6mqt122/1/)

It has the `input` expand the full width of a parent, in this case, `.input-group` which is set to the 80% I presume you wanted.